# Many tutorials on writing csv files have the mode set to 'wb', why?

Tags: python

For example: [Writing to csv file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745468/writing-to-csv-file-in-python)

```
with open('StockPrice.csv', 'wb') as f:
```

Why would we need to open in binary for a csv file?

Is this just habit, or is there a use-case for when binary is necessary for a csv file?

Comment: Sometimes binary mode increases I/O performance, IIRC.

Comment: It's because the [documentation for the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) says it's required. I've never figured out why though, it's very counter-intuitive.

Comment: I was right: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981576/2301450

Comment: @frostnational certainly binary is faster, but that seems unlikely to be the reason why it's called for here.

Comment: On Windows it's absolutely essential. On any other platform it does nothing at all (assuming you're using Python 2)

Comment: @Wooble, why is it essential?

Comment: Check out [this answer plus the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5546545/677122).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's necessary to use the mode `"wb"` when writing output using the `csv` module on Windows, because the `csv` module will write out line-ends as `\r\n` regardless of what platform you're running on.

If you're running on Windows, and you have a file open with mode `"w"`, Python will add an extra carriage return every time you write a newline.  So if you use a file with mode `"w"` to write output using the `csv` module, you will end up with `\r\r\n` line-endings, as both Python and the `csv` module have added carriage-return characters.

Here's a quick program that demonstrates the result.  Note that we read the file in binary mode (`"rb"`) to prevent Python from replacing `\r\n` with `\n` as it reads the file back in:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow([1,2,3,4])
    w.writerow([5,6,7,8])

with open("output.csv", "rb") as f:
    print repr(f.read())
```

When I run this on Windows, I get the following output:

```
'1,2,3,4\r\r\n5,6,7,8\r\r\n'
```